# bash script with simple regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Consider the following bash script with a simple regular expression:

```
for f in "$FILES"
do
  echo $f
  sed -i '/HTTP|RT/d' $f
done
```

This script shall read every file in the directory specified by `FILES` and remove the lines with occurrences of `'http'` or `'RT'` However, it seems that the OR part of the regular expression is not working. That is if I just have `sed -i '/HTTP/d' $f` then it will remove all lines containing `HTTP` but I cannot get it to remove both `HTTP` and `RT`

1. What must I change in my regular expression so that lines with `HTTP` or `RT` are removed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways of doing it (at least):

1. Having sed understand your regex:

   `sed -E -i '/HTTP|RT/d' $f`
2. Specifying each token separately:

   `sed -i '/HTTP/d;/RT/d' $f`

Comment: I tried `man sed` to look for the -E option. Obviously since this solution worked, I can see that it makes `sed` recognize my regex, but can you show me where to find the documentation?

Comment: `-E` is actually a synonym for `-r` (which would've also worked). `-E` is in there for [BSD backwards compatibility][1], and also what `man sed` on my OSX suggested.

[1]: http://blog.dmitryleskov.com/small-hacks/mysterious-gnu-sed-option-e/

Answer (score 1):

Before you do anything, run with the opposite, and PRINT what you plan to DELETE:

```
sed -n -e '/HTTP/p' -e '/RT/p' $f
```

Just to be sure you are deleting only what you want to delete before actually changing the files.

"It's not a question of whether you are paranoid or not, but whether you are paranoid ENOUGH."

Comment: hahaha I like the paranoid quote. However, I am already one step ahead as I have backup files :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, it will process all WORDS in the FILES variable.

If you want it to do all files in the FILES directory, then you need something like this:

```
for f in $( find $FILES -maxdepth 1 -type f )
do
   echo $f
    sed -i -e '/HTTP/d' -e '/RT/d' $f
done
```

You just need two "-e" options to sed.